# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token {

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors, cryptography

I have an encryption library that I am using for the mbed LPC1768 micro-controller.  I am now attempting to compile that same encryption library into custom firmware for the Espruino Pico which uses the STM32F401CDU6 micro-controller. However, I am receiving multiple compiling errors and I am not sure how to fix those errors to successfully compile the firmware using gcc-arm-none-eabi.

My compiling environment consists of VirtualBox running Ubuntu 14.04 as the guest OS and I am using gcc-arm-none-eabi to custom compile the Espruino Pico firmware.

**Compiling errors:**

```
CC libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.o
In file included from libs/crypto/cipher/BlockCipher.h:4:0,
                 from libs/crypto/cipher/AES.h:4,
                 from libs/crypto/crypto.h:4,
                 from libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.c:1:
libs/crypto/cipher/Cipher.h:12:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class Cipher
 ^
libs/crypto/cipher/Cipher.h:13:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 {
 ^
In file included from libs/crypto/cipher/AES.h:4:0,
                 from libs/crypto/crypto.h:4,
                 from libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.c:1:
libs/crypto/cipher/BlockCipher.h:13:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class BlockCipher : public Cipher
 ^
libs/crypto/cipher/BlockCipher.h:13:19: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token
 class BlockCipher : public Cipher
                   ^
In file included from libs/crypto/crypto.h:4:0,
                 from libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.c:1:
libs/crypto/cipher/AES.h:13:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
 class AES : public BlockCipher
 ^
libs/crypto/cipher/AES.h:13:11: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token
 class AES : public BlockCipher
           ^
libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.c: In function 'jswrap_aes_cbc':
libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.c:25:5: error: unknown type name 'AES'
     AES myAES(AES_128, myKEY, myIV, CBC_MODE); // specify all params, look at BlockCipher.h for modes
     ^
libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.c:25:5: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.c:28:10: error: request for member 'encrypt' in something not a structure or union
     myAES.encrypt(data, data, 0x80); // same in and out buffer can be used
          ^
libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.c:39:10: error: request for member 'decrypt' in something not a structure or union
     myAES.decrypt(data, data, 0x80);
          ^
make: *** [libs/crypto/jswrap_aes_cbc.o] Error 1
Build failed
```

**jswrap_aes_cbc.c file:**

```
#include "crypto.h"
#include "jswrap_aes_cbc.h"

#include "jsinteractive.h"



unsigned char myKEY[16] = { 'm', 'n', 'b', 'v', 'c', 'x', 'z', 'l', 'k', 'j', 'h', 'g', 'f', 'd', 's', 'a' };

unsigned char myIV[16] = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'p', 'o', 'i', 'u', 'y', 't', 'r' };

unsigned char data[0x80] = { };

// Let's define the JavaScript class that will contain our `aescbc()` method. We'll call it `Crypto`
/*JSON{
  "type" : "class",
  "class" : "Crypto"
}*/

// Now, we define the `jswrap_aes_cbc` to be a `staticmethod` on the `Crypto` class
/*JSON{
  "type" : "staticmethod",
  "class" : "Crypto",
  "name" : "aescbc",
  "generate" : "jswrap_aes_cbc"
}*/

void jswrap_aes_cbc()
{
    AES myAES(AES_128, myKEY, myIV, CBC_MODE); // specify all params, look at BlockCipher.h for modes
    jsiConsolePrint("\r\n\r\nFirst run\r\n");

    myAES.encrypt(data, data, 0x80); // same in and out buffer can be used

    jsiConsolePrint("\r\nEncrypted: ");

    /*for(char i=0; i<0x80; i++) 
    {
        //if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        //jsiConsolePrint(data[i]);
    }*/

    jsiConsolePrint("\r\nDecrypted again: ");

    myAES.decrypt(data, data, 0x80);

    /*for(char i=0; i<0x80; i++)
    {
        //if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        //jsiConsolePrint(data[i]);
    }*/
}
```

**BlockCipher.h file:**

```
#ifndef BLOCK_CIPHER_H
#define BLOCK_CIPHER_H

#include "Cipher.h"

enum BLOCK_CIPHER_MODE
{
    ECB_MODE,
    CBC_MODE,
    PCBC_MODE
};

class BlockCipher : public Cipher
{
    public :  

        BlockCipher(uint32_t bs, BLOCK_CIPHER_MODE m, uint8_t *iv = 0);
        virtual ~BlockCipher();

        virtual CIPHER_TYPE getType() const;        
        uint32_t getBlockSize() const;
        void setIV(uint8_t *iv);

        virtual void encrypt(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in, uint32_t length);        
        virtual void decrypt(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in, uint32_t length);        

    protected :

        virtual void encryptBlock(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in) = 0;
        virtual void decryptBlock(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in) = 0;

    private :

        uint32_t blockSize;
        BLOCK_CIPHER_MODE mode;
        uint8_t *IV;
        uint8_t *tmpIV;
        uint8_t *tmpdatain;
        uint8_t *tmpdata;

};

#endif
```

**AES.h file:**

```
#ifndef AES_H
#define AES_H

#include "BlockCipher.h"

enum AES_TYPE
{
    AES_128 = 4,
    AES_192 = 6,
    AES_256 = 8
};

class AES : public BlockCipher
{
    public :

        AES(const AES_TYPE type, uint8_t *key);
        AES(const AES_TYPE type, uint8_t *key, uint8_t *iv, BLOCK_CIPHER_MODE m=CBC_MODE);

        void keyExpansion(uint8_t *key);

    private :

        virtual void encryptBlock(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in);
        virtual void decryptBlock(uint8_t *out, uint8_t *in);

        uint32_t rotWord(uint32_t w);
        uint32_t invRotWord(uint32_t w);        
        uint32_t subWord(uint32_t w);
        void subBytes();
        void invSubBytes();
        void shiftRows();
        void invShiftRows();
        void mul(uint8_t *r);
        void invMul(uint8_t *r);
        void mixColumns();
        void invMixColumns();
        void addRoundKey(int round);

        uint8_t state[16];
        uint32_t w[60];
        uint8_t nr,nk;
};

#endif
```

Comment: You have included a `cpp` header in a `c` file.

Comment: `class` is a `C++` thing. You cannot expect that to be compiled with a `C` compiler.

Comment: You are using an object of `class AES` in your file `jswrap_aes_cbc.c`.

There is no concept of `class` in `C` programming language, so you should either use some `C` interfaces or change your source file to appropriate `c++` extension and use some `C++` compiler to compile the program.

Comment: Is this solved (in the sense that you know what is wrong now) with the comments above?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes, this is solved.  I now understand classes are for C++ and I would have to convert the library to C which is beyond the scope of my knowledge.  I continued my search for a cryptography C library and found [tiny-AES128-C](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES128-C). tiny-AES128-C seems to work as expected.

Comment: @dottedquad Glad you got something working! Could you however delete the question here? Otherwise it stays in the close queue (always a problem on SO) or it remains unanswered. Beware that ECB is insecure and that CBC only provides for confidentiality, not integrity or authentication - and that only when used correctly.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I was considering sha256 the IV+LengthofOriginalString+data is there anything else that I should consider doing?

Comment: Yes, you probably should do either HMAC over the IV, use AES-CMAC (*not* CBC-MAC) or use an authenticated cipher. Anybody can calculate a hash.

Comment: My environment is a STM32F401CDU6 CPU - ARM Cortex M4, 384kb flash, 96kb RAM which has minimal resources.  the STM32 is currently connected to an Intel Edison(takes care of encryption and network).  But, I prefer the STM32 instantaneous boot-up times vs the intel edison bootup.  So I decided to find another alternative for encryption and find a C encryption library small enough to work on the STM32F401CDU6. the tiny-AES128 library.